# Error in mac code

Tags: xcode, macos, compiler-construction

I found this linking errors in MAC code can't find why they are shown :(.

Please help.

> 

```
NetworkHandler::HandleSipPacket(char*, int) in networkhandler.o
  "MsSipAgent::BuildSessionProgressToInvite(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      NetworkHandler::HandleSipPacket(char*, int) in networkhandler.o
  "MsSipAgent::Build200OkResponseToInvite(std::string const&, std::string const&)", referenced from:
      NetworkHandler::HandleSipPacket(char*, int) in networkhandler.o
  "MsSipAgent::BuildDeclineMessageToInvite()", referenced from:
      NetworkHandler::HandleSipPacket(char*, int) in networkhandler.o
  "MsSipAgent::BuildAckMessageForFinalResponse()", referenced from:
      NetworkHandler::HandleSipPacket(char*, int) in networkhandler.o
  "MsSipAgent::BuildReInviteRequest(std::string&)", referenced from:
      NetworkHandler::SendReinvite() in networkhandler.o
  "MsSipAgent::BuildByeRequestToInvite()", referenced from:
      NetworkHandler::Hangup() in networkhandler.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Specially please help me to understand the line:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line is a summary of the problems that were reported before it.  The linker couldn't find a number of functions belonging to a class called `MsSipAgent`.  Presumably, this is some C++ thing that you should be building into your project (or adding as a library).